# Finding position vector given another position vector describing the same path

Tags: derivatives, vectors

An animation has two scenes, each of them being one second long. In the first scene, an object moves along the path $$p_{1}(t)= ( -3t^2+7t,-2t^2-8,2t^2-2t-3)$$ for $0 ≤ t ≤ 1$. At the end of the scene, the object’s acceleration immediately becomes zero, and remains zero throughout the second scene.The vector-valued function $p_{2}(t)$ for the object’s path in the second scene also uses $0 ≤ t ≤ 1$, so that $t = 0$ in the second scene is the same moment as $t = 1$ in the first scene. What is $p_{2}(t)$ ?

My work :

$$p_{2}(t)=(at^2+bt+c_{1},dt^2+et+c_{2},ft^2+gt+c_{3}) $$

Since acceleration is zero throughout the second scene, $a=d=f=0$ . Since both functions describe the same path at different time, $p_{1}(1)=p_{2}(0)$, so $c_{1}=4,c_{2}=-10,c_{3}=-3$

I am not sure about this step but I equate the integral of $p''_{1}(t)$ from $0$ to $1$ with $p'_{2}(0)$ to get $b=-3,e=-4,g=4$.

So $p_{2}(t) = ( -3t+4,-4t-10,4t-3)$

Is this method ( and the ans) correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the object will move in the second time interval with the same velocity as it reached at the end of the first time interval, and remain moving with constant velocity.

In which case, the velocity is $$\frac{dp_1}{dt}=\left(\begin{matrix}-6t+7\\-4t\\4t-2\end{matrix}\right)$$ $$=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-4\\2\end{matrix}\right)$$

Since the second motion starts from where the particle ended the first motion, which is $$\left(\begin{matrix}4\\-10\\-3\end{matrix}\right)$$
Therefore $$p_2=\left(\begin{matrix}4+t\\-10-4t\\-3+2t\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: This is correct and l finally understand it. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: you are welcome